# Is it possible to get the x and y coordinates of a touch?

Tags: ios, touch, coordinates

is it possible to get the x and y coordinates of a touch? If so could someone please provide a very simple example where the coordinates are just logged to the console.

Comment: Have you read the UITouch Class reference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Using touchesBegan Event**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Touch x : %f y : %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
}
```

This event is triggered when touch starts.

**Using Gesture**

Register your UITapGestureRecognizer in `viewDidLoad:` Method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureRecognizer:)];
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
```

Setting up the tapGestureRecognizer function

```
// Tap GestureRecognizer function
- (void)tapGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint tappedPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat xCoordinate = tappedPoint.x;
    CGFloat yCoordinate = tappedPoint.y;

    NSLog(@"Touch Using UITapGestureRecognizer x : %f y : %f", xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
}
```

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d414u2mmxd6fxp4/TouchCoordiantes.zip)

Comment: Going off of the first method you gave, using the touches began, how can I make the x and y positions global variables?

Comment: Create a CGPoint variable in your .h file and assign it in the above methoh

Comment: The touches began work great, but I am unable to get touchesEnded to work, isn't almost the exact same thing?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add a gesture recognizer to the view you want.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *myTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myTapRecognizer:)];
[self.myView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.myView addGestureRecognizer:myTap];
```

Then in the gesture recognizer method you make a call to `locationInView:`

```
- (void)myTapRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint tappedPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.myView];
    CGFloat xCoordinate = tappedPoint.x;
    CGFloat yCoordinate = tappedPoint.y;
}
```

You may want to take a look at apple's [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic example (place it inside your view controller):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(currentPoint));
}
```

This triggers every time the touch moves. You can also use `touchesBegan:withEvent:` which triggers when a touch starts, and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` which triggers when a touch ends (i.e. a finger is lifted).

You can also do this using a `UIGestureRecognizer`, which in many cases is more practical.

Comment: I c/p this into my view controller and I got an error with the NSLog, but it was fixed by changing the string to NSSringFromCGPoint. But I still did not recieve anything in the console, am I missing something? Thanks for your help

Comment: You shouldn't have to add any extra code to make this work. Could something else be capturing the touch event (e.g. is there a subview like a button that could be stopping the touch from getting through to the viewController's view)?

Comment: Essentially, any view on added to the viewController's `self.view` that doesn't have `.userInteractionEnabled = NO` would capture the touch and stop it from going to the methods given in the answer above.